# Why does Path Analysis fail when using a composite score?

Tags: regression, composite, r-lavaan

I'm attempting to use `lavaan` to run a path analysis on reading assessment data (no latent variables), and it fails usually with this error:

```
    In lav_model_estimate(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavpartable = lavpartable,  :
      lavaan WARNING: the optimizer warns that a solution has NOT been found
```

Although the data is relatively large, I've discerned that the root of the issue is this part of the model: `reading ~ a + b + c`

`a`,`b` and `c` are all scores from 0-30, and they're basically 3 different groups of words.  'reading' is an elementary composite score (i.e., for each child, 'reading' is adding together `a+b+c`).

Removing any one of a, b or c produces a 'successful' result, so I'm led to believe that somehow there is *too much* information in the model?

a, b and c are not particularly unusually correlated with each other - between 0.3 and 0.37.

Is there any reason why a path analysis would fail because of using a composite score like this, even though there's variation within the scores?

Comment: I do not understand why you are doing a multiple linear regression using predictors (i.v.s) that are contained already in the dependent variable. If reading is a component containing the common information of a, b, and c, what is the rationale behind your model? Have you tried PCA?

Comment: So this might be displaying my ignorance, but I don't think PCA is necessary because all the variables in the model are observed. 

The reason for doing it is because we want to see if engaging in a reading intervention has changed how each of the sets of words (a,b,c) contribute to the overall score (reading) compared to a control group, but within a larger model.

There's also multiple other tests of reading and comprehension, which also fit into this wider model. And we want to see how variation in a,b and c contribute to the overall score of reading, and then comprehension.

Comment: PCA is a technique for dimensionality reduction. EFA is different, you assume that you have a d. v. (latent) which manifests itself in your items (manifest variables). I do not understand how do you want to see prediction in a variable that is a composite of all the predictors.

Comment: I'm happy to accept that I'm missing some important theoretical understanding here. 

But what I want to be able to see is, within a larger model, there is a significant difference between a,b and c. So, for example, it might be that the overall score for 'reading' is the same in groups 1 and 2, but in group 1, test 'a' is improved at the expense of test 'c', and vice-versa in group 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some comments, I think that I understand what you want. My suggestion is to assume reading as a latent variable (something which is common in the [literature](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11145-010-9278-3)) a run multigroup confirmatory factor analysis to test for potential differences among groups.

```r
model <- "reading =~ a + b + c"

semTools::measurementInvariance(model=model, data=df, group="variable of grouping")
```

If measurement invariance holds, your groups do not differ in terms of fit. If not, you can investigate where it fails (using the Δχ² criterion or the ΔCFI criterion or other).

Example:

```r
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3'
semTools::measurementInvariance(model=HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939,group="school")
```

Alternatively, to semTools, you can use `lavaan` function:

```r
library(lavaan)
fit <- cfa(model=model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939, group="school", group.equal=c("loadings")) #then if it holds, group.equal=c("loadings", "intercepts"))
```

If you want to specifically compare two groups regarding a specific parameter:

```r
model_free <- "visual  =~ x1 + c(l1,l2)*x2 + x3"
fit_model_free <- cfa(model=model_free, data=HolzingerSwineford1939, group="school")

model_equal <- "visual  =~ x1 + c(l3,l3)*x2 + x3"
fit_model_equal <- cfa(model=model_equal, data=HolzingerSwineford1939, group="school")

lavaan::anova(fit_model_free, fit_model_equal) #LRT test
```

If the models differ, it means that one loading in one group presents statistically significant differences from the loading of the other group.

In this, example, no:

```r
(¬_¬)lavaan::anova(fit_model_free, fit_model_equal)
Chi-Squared Difference Test

                Df    AIC    BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)
fit_model_free   0 2718.0 2784.8 0.0000                              
fit_model_equal  1 2716.2 2779.3 0.2078    0.20782       1     0.6485
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It's very helpful - I think this makes sense for what I would like to do. 

I'm happy to accept a path analysis simply can't cope with (or isn't designed for) including a composite score with no error. Are you aware of a theoretical reason why that's the case?

Comment: Path analysis is one application of structural equation modeling, another application is to use reading as a latent variable (assuming) the measurement error, and use a structural model. Path analysis does not use latent variables. If the presented solution solved your problem, please mark it as a solution.